# Creating layers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an app that uses AngularJS and Bootstrap. The basic structure of my app is like this:

**home.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="container">
    The main content goes here
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="showScreenA()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></span></button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="showScreenB()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span></button>      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**home.js**

```
myApp.controller('MyController', [function($scope) {
  $scope.showScreenA = function() {
    // Display screen A whether screen B is open or if the main content is shown. 
    // No difference.
  };

  $scope.showScreenB = function() {
    // Display screen B whether screen A is open or if the main content is shown. 
    // No difference.
  };
}]);
```

Ideally, I would like a div to animate in from the top with Screen A or Screen B. The div cannot cover the footer in any way. I thought about several options. However, I can't figure out a good way to do this. At first, I thought about using the Bootstrap Modal. However, I couldn't get it to work with the footer. In addition, there was more chrome than I wanted.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Show us how you tried to show modals.

Comment: Let me understand: When the user clicks one of the buttons in the footer then the corresponding content should appear in the area identified as div.container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control visibility with `ng-show` and animation with `ngAnimate`.

I made a plunkr with a simple example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4GcqBpOB5lBiGVv3YhK5?p=preview

Please make sure to add angular-animate.js to your page and to inject `ngAnimate` in your app:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showScreenA = function() {
    $scope.screen = 'A'; 
  };

  $scope.showScreenB = function() {
    $scope.screen = 'B';
  };
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I like your solution. However, I have one question. How is screen A and screen B always appearing on top of the main content? Your solution properly overlays the main content. In my solution, the screen appears. However, the main content sits on top of the screen. I expected this as the main content HTML comes after the screens. However, your solution behaves the way I want. Yet, I can't figure out why.

Comment: Nice, that behaviour is done with css, please take a look at the CSS file, the `.screen` class, the `position: absolute` does the trick. Please mark as answer if that is the case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to do with your page. I suggest that not writing two individual functions though, you'd be better served using a single function and pass (A or B) as a parameter, then write conditional statements.

```
ng-click="showScreen(a) & ng-click="showScreen(b)


$scope.showScreen = function(item){
   if(item === a){} else if (item === b){};
}
```

I'd set the z-index for the footer to a higher value and set the div you want to appear from the function to have a lower z-index in the CSS without changing it in your controller code.